# Generating realizations over time with specific variance

Tags: probability, matlab

My questions is as follows;
Suppose, there is a vector of N elements such that probability mass function (PMF) at time $t$ is as follows:

$A(t) = [a_1(t), a_2(t), ..., a_N(t)]$

Now, at time $t+1$, we make a rule that A(t+1) should be generated with a specific variance $\sigma^2$ such that the properties of PMF are met.

How can we generate it in MATLAB?

Comment: If $A(t)$ is already given for all $t>0$, then what exactly do you mean about the variance?

Comment: Maybe, the question is not clear. I formulate it again.
At $t=1$, we generate $A(t)$ where each element has a specific probability.

At $t=2$, we would like to perturbation the values of each element such that the properties of PMF are met.

Suppose $A(1) = [0.6 0.35 0.05]$. When $\sigma^2 = 0.05$, then how does the resulting PMF look like at $t=2$?

Comment: And what exactly is the relation between $A(t)$ and $A(t + 1)$? Perturbation is too vague to mean anything concrete.

Comment: Can you please emphasize about kind of relation is it that is relevant?

Comment: It depends on specific contexts. It would be better if you show the complete background and question.